# Woocommerce not loading assets (JS/CSS)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

`Woocommerce` is not loading my assets. I can see all my other theme assets files like css, js and all that works perfectly. I have my header and footer in place on the checkout page, in my `header.php` I got my `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in place and that seems to work alright except for `Woocommerce`.

Currently my checkout is loading purely the html without any assets. JS wont work (eg. clicking to toggle coupons field), css wont load.

How may I solve this? tried to override the `form-checkout.php` (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php) and force my `get_header` and `get_footer`, without any success.

Comment: added small statement changes and highlighting keywords.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to find if for some reason your theme is disabling it? 
look for code like this - `add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );` OR `define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_USE_CSS', false );`

Comment: I cannot find this at all in my code, maybe enqueue it? Have tried a few ways but without any success. How would you approach this?

Comment: can you try to add this: define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_USE_CSS', true ); to your functions.php and see if this works?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @ShirGans Sorry I cannot. But for sure the CSS/JS is not loading at all, but other assets are. Loading from mix laravel.